# Using Observer Zookeeper in Kafka DR scenario

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

If we have a **stretch kafka cluster** of two DCs with 6 brokers and 5 zookeepers, split in below fashion:

**DC1** : 3 zookeepers & 3 brokers ; **DC2** : 2 zookeepers & 3 brokers

For a DR scenario in case, DC1 fails. How can we use a spare zookeeper, say an observer zookeeper(preferably in cloud) to come for the rescue and avoid a disaster?
Can an extra zookeeper serve a DR situation?
Suggestions welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how an extra Zookeeper will save you here.

If you had a replication factor of 3, then a DC is down, you're potentially losing entire topics that are on those brokers. Even if one replica is available, then any producer with acks=all or a topic config of min ISR = 2, will start causing issues

Comment: How about keeping 3 brokers in each DC?

Comment: Sure, that would be better. I assume you've read the whitepapers on this? https://www.confluent.io/blog/3-ways-prepare-disaster-recovery-multi-datacenter-apache-kafka-deployments